# How do I use a computed property in a child Vue component using vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Consider a computed property of:

```
  computed: {
menuItems (){
  let menuItems = [
    {icon:'dashboard', title:'Home', link:'/'},
    {icon:'fa-code', title:'Code Portfolio', link:'/code'},
    {icon:'fa-rss', title:'Blog', link:'/'},
    {icon:'fa-info-circle', title:'About', link:'/'},
    {icon:'fa-envelope', title:'Contact', link:'/'},
  ]
  return menuItems
}}
```

Using vue-router, how do I pass this array to the child component?

I've tried declaring the prop in the component and binding it to router-link:

Component:

```
props: ['menuItems']
```

Parent:

```
<router-view :menuItems="menuItems"></router-view>
```

This isn't working. How do I correctly pass the prop, or is there a better way to do it entirely. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly `:menu-items="menuItems"` depending on how your template is defined. If it is in DOM, it needs to be kebab-cased. Otherwise it's something else.

Comment: To clarify, I am using a computed property instead of just a data property because it will later interact with an authorization state.

Comment: @Bert, good suggestion. I missed that. Still not working though.

Comment: Interesting. Up until 2.7, that would have worked. As of 2.8 it's not.

Comment: They broke it *yesterday* heh.  I guess this assumes you are using 2.8 or 3.0. If you are, try reverting to 2.7. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1800

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a computed method with static data (or with data that, once the component is created, will never change. You could simply use the data property of the component.

Then: what are you tryng to do? Maybe you need a menu component? You can declare your App (or main component)'s template in this way:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <custom-menu></custom-menu>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

In your custom-menu component you can handle your menu links, if they change based on the route

Comment: Thanks @Radar155. It will eventually be a dynamic property once I tie it to an Auth state later. And I need the items to render something other than a nav bar.

Comment: you should use vuex to store the application data in a centralized store shared by all components. Here you can store auth state and all components will react to changes based on your logic.

Comment: Usually I would but I only have this single data point that needs to be shared and was trying to avoid vuex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how to pass an dynamic object through as a prop but I think I was overthinking the whole thing.

From the vue.js documentation: "It is often overlooked that the source of truth in Vue applications is the raw data object"

Since I was only trying to get an authorization state passed down globally to my components it was simplest to just reference the root data instance.

So in any component that I need that data I just create a computed property:

```
computed: {
    user(){
      return this.$root.$data.user
    }
  }
```

In cases where the root data is dynamic or their are lots of global data vuex works great. I just didn't want to use it for this small project.